# User Creation in AD

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV File of Employee Details and want to perform Create,Modify and Disable actions based on the Status of Employee. Following the CSV.

```
EmployeeCode,EmployeeID,EmployeName,Firstname,Lastname,Email,Designation,Department,State,ReportingManagerCode,Status
XA0001,1256,Srihari T,Srihari,T,srihari.t@contosso.com,Executive,Finance,Kerala,1258,New
XA0002,1257,Adam Varghese,Adam,Varghese,adam.varghese@contosso.com,TL,CC,Tamil Nadu,1210,Disabled
XA0003,1258,Shakti Velu,Shakti,Velu,shakti.velu@contosso.com,Manager,Finance,Kerala,1205,Existing
```

Following the OU Structure.

```
contosso.com
    Finance(OU=Finance,DC=contosso,DC=com)
    CC(OU=CC,DC=contosso,DC=com)
    Left(OU=Left,DC=contosso,DC=com)
```

Expecting Solution: If a user status is "New" then user gets created in their Department OU along with other Attributes. Status "Disabled" Users gets disabled and move to Left OU. And Status "Existing" user gets their attributes updated.

For each action i have separate PowerShell Script working but unable to combine them in to single script by checking the Status Field.

1. Able to Create users but cannot lookup the Status as "New" to create it.

```
Import-Module activedirectory
$ADUsers = Import-csv 'C:\IT\EmployeeDetails.csv'

foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{       
    $Username   = ($User.Firstname + '.' + $User.Lastname).ToLower()
    $Firstname  = $User.Firstname
    $Lastname   = $User.Lastname
    $OU         = 'OU=Finance,DC=contosso,DC=com'
    $Email      = $User.Email
    $EmployeeID = $User.EmployeeID
    $State      = $User.State
    $Designation   = $User.Designation
    $Department = $User.Department
    $Password = (Get-RandomCharacters -characters AbcDeFgHiJkLmNoPqRsTuVwXyZ!@#*123456789 -length 8)

    #Check to see if the user already exists in AD
    if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $Username})
    {
         Write-Warning "A user account with username $Username already exist in Active Directory."
    }
    else
    {
        New-ADUser `
            -SamAccountName $Username `
            -UserPrincipalName "$Username@contosso.com" `
            -Name "$Firstname $Lastname" `
            -GivenName $Firstname `
            -Surname $Lastname `
            -Enabled $True `
            -DisplayName "$Firstname $Lastname" `
            -Path $OU `
            -EmployeeID $EmployeeID `
            -State $State `
            -EmailAddress $Email `
            -Title $Designation `
            -Department $Department `
            -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True

    }
}
```

2. Disables the user but cannot lookup on the Status as "Disabled" to disable and move to Left OU.

```
Import-Module activedirectory

$ADUsers = Import-csv C:\IT\EmployeeDetails.csv

foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
    Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$($User.EmployeeID)'" | 
    Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Left,DC=contosso,DC=com" -PassThru | 
    Disable-ADAccount
}
```

3. Modify details but unable to lookup Status as "Existing" to modify it.

```
Import-Module activedirectory

$ADUsers = Import-Csv C:\IT\EmployeeDetails.csv

foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$($User.EmployeeID)'" | 
Set-ADUser -EmailAddress $User.Email -Title $User.Designation -Department $User.Department -State $User.State
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create one script out of these parts, I'd suggest creating three functions for

1. Create a new user
2. Move and disable an existing user and
3. Update an existing user

and call any of these in a main loop depending on what the `Status` value in the CSV is.

Something like below:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

function New-User ($record) {
    $AccountName = ($record.Firstname + '.' + $record.Lastname).ToLower()

    #Check to see if the user already exists in AD
    if (Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$AccountName'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
         $msg = "New-User: a user account with username $AccountName already exist in Active Directory."
         Write-Warning $msg
    }
    else {
        $FullName = ('{0} {1}' -f $record.Firstname, $record.Lastname).Trim()
        $OU       = 'OU={0},DC=contosso,DC=com' -f $record.Department
        $Password = (Get-RandomCharacters -characters AbcDeFgHiJkLmNoPqRsTuVwXyZ!@#*123456789 -length 8)

        $userParams = @{
            SamAccountName        = $AccountName
            UserPrincipalName     = "$AccountName@contosso.com"
            Name                  = $FullName
            GivenName             = $record.Firstname
            Surname               = $record.Lastname
            Enabled               = $true
            DisplayName           = $FullName
            Path                  = $OU
            EmployeeID            = $record.EmployeeID
            State                 = $record.State
            EmailAddress          = $record.Email
            Title                 = $record.Designation
            Department            = $record.Department
            AccountPassword       = (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force)
            ChangePasswordAtLogon = $true
        }
        # create the user and report back
        New-ADUser @userParams

        # don't forget to output the initial password, the user needs this for the first-time login.
        $msg = "New-User: created user $AccountName. Initial password: $Password"
    }
    # report back
    $msg
}

function Move-User ($record) {
    # check if the user object exists
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$($record.EmployeeID)'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if (!$user) {
        $msg = "Move-User: a user account with EmployeeID $($record.EmployeeID) does not exist."
        Write-Warning $msg
    }
    else {
        $OU = "OU=Left,DC=contosso,DC=com"
        $user | Set-ADUser -Enabled $false
        $user | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Left,DC=contosso,DC=com"

        $msg = "Move-User: user $($user.SamAccountName) disabled and moved to $OU"
    }
    # report back
    $msg
}

function Update-User ($record) {
    # check if the user object exists
    $props = 'EmailAddress', 'Title', 'Department', 'State'
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$($record.EmployeeID)'" -Properties $props -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if (!$user) {
        $msg = "Update-User: a user account with EmployeeID $($record.EmployeeID) does not exist."
        Write-Warning $msg
    }
    else {
        $userParams = @{
            EmailAddress = $record.Email
            Title        = $record.Designation
            Department   = $record.Department
            State        = $record.State
        }
        $user | Set-ADUser @userParams

        $msg = "Update-User: user $($user.SamAccountName) updated"
    }
    # report back
    $msg
}

$result = Import-Csv 'C:\IT\EmployeeDetails.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    # perform the actions New, Move or Update
    switch ($_.Status) {
        'New'      { New-User $_ ; break}
        'Disabled' { Move-User $_ ; break}
        'Existing' { Update-User $_ ; break}
        default    { "ERROR: Unknown Status in CSV: $_" }
    }
}

# output the messages on screen
$result

# or write to file
$result | Set-Content -Path 'C:\IT\EmployeeResults.txt'
```

Note that I cannot check what your function `Get-RandomCharacters` does, but I'm assuming that performs OK.

<sup>Not that it matters in this code, but there is a typo in one of the headers of your CSV: `EmployeName` should be `EmployeeName`</sup>